# Hive SQL Join ON fields with conditional equal operation to ignore NULLs

Tags: sql, hive, null, hiveql

I have a Table A as

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 VALUE
1   A   xx  100
1   A   yy  200
1   A   yy  100
1   A       100
1   B   zz  300
2   B   yy  300
2   C   yy  400
```

Table B has actions or rules as below and it can written on more than 3 ID fields

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 ACTION
    A   xx  GetAxx
    A   yy  GetAyy
    B       GetB
```

I want to join the tables and produce the result as below

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 TOTAL
1   A   xx  100
1   A   yy  200
1   A   yy  100
1   B   zz  300
2   B   yy  300
```

I tried simple OR condition and also conditional joins, however got the same error
FAILED: SemanticException Cartesian products are disabled for safety reasons. If you know what you are doing, please sethive.strict.checks.cartesian.product to false and that hive.mapred.mode is not set to 'strict' to proceed.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B
ON
(B.ID1 IS NULL OR A.ID1=B.ID1) AND
(B.ID2 IS NULL OR A.ID2=B.ID2) AND
(B.ID3 IS NULL OR A.ID3=B.ID3)

SELECT * FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B
ON
(COALESCE(A.ID1,"NA")=COALESCE(B.ID1, A.ID1, "NA") and
(COALESCE(A.ID2,"NA")=COALESCE(B.ID2, A.ID2, "NA") and
(COALESCE(A.ID3,"NA")=COALESCE(B.ID3, A.ID3, "NA")
```

Whats the right way to conditionally join on multiple fields while ignoring null comparison from join condition 
or 
is there a way to force the condition to equate to true when there is null in Table B 
or
is there a way to force match null from Table B with with any value in Table A to return true

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can achive result by directly applying inner join on column ID2,ID3.

```
SELECT A.ID1,A.ID2,A.ID3,A.VALUE as total FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B
ON
A.ID2=B.ID2 and
A.ID3=B.ID3
```

Comment: this would return only when the ID matches. What I want is to ignore the join condition when there is null in a field in the Table_A

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1
              from b
              where (b.id1 = a.id1 or b.id1 is null) and
                    (b.id2 = a.id2 or b.id2 is null) and
                    (b.id3 = a.id3 or b.id3 is null)
             );
```

You can actually do this using `JOIN` as well, but that could result in duplicate rows under some circumstances:

```
select a.*
from a join
     b
    on (b.id1 = a.id1 or b.id1 is null) and
       (b.id2 = a.id2 or b.id2 is null) and
        (b.id3 = a.id3 or b.id3 is null);
```

Comment: Tried it in Hive. Got same error FAILED: SemanticException Cartesian products are disabled for safety reasons. If you know what you are doing, please sethive.strict.checks.cartesian.product to false and that hive.mapred.mode is not set to 'strict' to proceed. condition ---> b.id is null triggers the error message

Comment: Both queries returns only  3 records                                                                                `id1 id2 id3 value
1 A XX 100
1 A YY 200
1 A YY 100`